# Is there any sort of Operating System API that can encode/decode, or securely store a secret for you?

Tags: security

Is there any sort of Operating System API that can encode/decode, or securely store a secret for you? On Linux, OSX, Windows

background: You need to store a password securely. If you encipher the password with your program, an attacker could disassemble your binary and retrieve the encryption key.

If there's another way to accomplish this, I'm also open for suggestions.

Comment: Disassembling your binary to retrieve the key applies to the OS as well.

Comment: you could leave yourself a series of clues to follow in case you're neuralyzed and want to get your memory of your password back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OS X has that capability.  It's called a keychain.  The way it works is that the OS allows access to the keychain item if your app is the one that originally stored it (usually using code signing to ensure that it is the same app) or if you have set an ACL to allow specific additional apps access to that item, and only when the keychain's owning user is currently logged in.  The act of signing in with the user's password unlocks the keychain, so if the user loses his/her password, the keychain must be replaced with an empty one, because it becomes worthless at that point.

iOS provides a similar keychain, but it is unlocked by the device's passcode, and the keychain is per-app instead of shared across apps, which means keys can't be shared very easily across apps unless the apps themselves explicitly request access to a shared keychain.

I would assume that other OSes have similar features.